# Can object creation affect application performance

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I am trying to solve performance problem of an application. GC repots says (available at below link) that object creation rate is too high but I see in 20 mins of run, GC process was not really bad, so how does object creation matters here if GC is not running for long. After doing some micro benchmarking, I noticed few sections of code (no database call only in-memory computation) takes about 2 minutes to process with 100 user load but in single user load runs in 2 secs. I suspect that there might be thread contention issue as there are 20 background threads running (excluding tomcat thread pool). Could the Object creation rate be the root cause? (as mentioned in below link)

http://gceasy.io/my-gc-report.jsp?p=c2hhcmVkLzIwMTgvMDUvMy8tLWdjbG9nLmxvZy0tMTgtNTUtMjg=

Comment: The link to the report isn’t working anymore, I think you might have to host the file yourself somewhere? Anyway this leaves not much to go on in your question.

Comment: @millimoose thanks, yea noticed that. it should be fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GC log definitely shows some memory issue. The key points are:

```
Minor GC count  352
Minor GC reclaimed  534.76 gb
Minor GC total time 1 min 40 sec 680 ms
Minor GC avg time   286 ms
Minor GC avg time std dev   272 ms
Minor GC min/max time   10 ms / 970 ms
Minor GC Interval avg   3 sec 334 ms
```

**Based on these metrics your application generates 1.5 Gb of garbage every 3.5 seconds.**

If you are not doing specifically memory intensive tasks (like financial simulations), then it is a huge number and must be investigated.

I suggest using a debugger tool that can do memory profiling. JProfiler would surely do the job, but maybe just with a JVisualVM (already installed on your machine as part of the jdk) you will be able to track down what is allocating that much memory.